# Trigger different events based on how long mouse is held down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger different events based on how long the mouse is held down. If the mouse is held less than a second trigger event 1. If it is held down for a second trigger event 2. If it is held down for two seconds trigger event 3, etc.

I have this JavaScript which displays messages showing how long the mouse is held down, but I am unsure of how to prevent the message shown after one second if the user continues to hold the mouse down for two seconds,

```
var mousedown = false;
var mousedown_timer = '';
$('#button').mousedown(function(e) {
  mousedown = true;
  $('#log').text('mousedown...');
  mousedown_timer = setTimeout(function () {
      if(mousedown) {
        $('#log').text('1 second');
      }
  }, 1000);
  mousedown_timer = setTimeout(function () {
    if(mousedown) {
        $('#log').text('2 second');
    }
  }, 2000);
}).mouseup(function(e) {
mousedown = false;
clearTimeout(mousedown_timer);
$('#log').text('aborted');
});
```

Is there maybe a way I could move my timer to detect the time elapsed in the mouseup function?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b1Lzo60n/20/) is a fiddle.

Comment: Just wondering.  I wouldn't think this is an intuitive action to most people on web pages. Are they going to know of this functionality when they use your site?  I am wondering what the real problem you are trying to solve by implementing the timed mousedown/up type of functionality?  I would guess that it would actually frustrate people if they accidentally delay  their mouseup not knowing the consequence (if it is not obvious).  Just my opinion though.  Think how hard it is going to be to trigger event 2.

Comment: It's not really for a traditional webpage. I'm making a step sequencer with the web audio api. The length the button is held down is intended to determine the length of the note that is added to the sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
var mousedownTimestamp;
$('#button').mousedown(function(e) {
  mousedownTimestamp = new Date();
}).mouseup(function(e) {
  var mouseupTimestamp = new Date();
  var difference = mouseupTimestamp - mousedownTimestamp;
  if (difference < 1000) {
     // event 1
  } else if (difference >= 1000 && difference < 2000) {
     // event 2
  } else if (difference >= 2000) {
     // event 3
  }
});
```